# ROS 2 Docker humble release

Tags: ros2, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any date for the official release of the ROS 2 Humble docker images? I see the roadmap and the freeze dates but I cannot find when is going to be released the docker image.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400731/ros-2-docker-humble-release/) by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 443 on 2022-05-17

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [Distributions Documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Releases.html) lists the 23rd May 2022 as the release date for Humble.
Not sure if this includes the docker images, but the [Release Checklist found on GitHub](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1149) includes the (still unchecked) point `Create new Docker images for Humble` under `Late development cycle`.

I see that the checklist was updated 7 days ago, but I don't know if this really is an active document.

---

Originally posted by [krsche](https://answers.ros.org/users/105251/krsche/) with karma: 36 on 2022-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) on 2022-05-19**:
Thanks a lot

**Comment by [ashish5679](https://answers.ros.org/users/105800/ashish5679/) on 2022-05-24**:
Here is official humble:
https://hub.docker.com/layers/ros/library/ros/humble/images/sha256-a170eaed292d7817363063540d4b955c98c284a8e3e6e3a32ce95ada819f1367?context=explore